# How can I make user to input an int value and split them up to single number and put in array?

Tags: java

So I want to give user input an int value.

```
System.out.println ("How many number does your Student number has?");
tn = sc.nextInt();
int [] number = new int[tn];
System.out.println ("What is your Student number?");
for (int i = 0; i < tn; i++)
{    
number[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

So as you guys can see, after the first println If we input 2, the will print the second println twice, but i want it to be print only once, but user will only be able to place 2 digit number.

so for example if the tn was 2, the student number can only placed 10 - 99.

Comment: If you must split student number into individual digits, ask user for the entire number, then split it in code. E.g. user enters `34567`, and *you* write code to make that an array of size 5 with values `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7`.

Comment: But it will put those number in reverse order, assuming I use the %10 method, I was asked to take out all the even position of number, so it will be messed up.

Comment: It will only put the numbers in reverse order if you don't code it correctly.

Comment: And it doesn't necessarily matter if you _do_ get the digits in reverse order.  The first digit is just now at position 4 in your array of digits instead of position 0, the second at position 3 instead of position 1, etc. (assuming a five-digit number to start with...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615207/how-can-i-make-user-to-input-an-int-value-and-split-them-up-to-single-number-and#comment82188800_47615207):

> I was asked to take out all the even position of number

Assuming that the even positions of number `234567` are digits `3`, `5`, and `7`, you can do it easily by converting to string and extracting those characters, like this:

```
private static int[] getEveryOtherDigit(int n) {
    String s = Integer.toString(n);
    int[] result = new int[s.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2, j++)
        result[j] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(7)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(67)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(567)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(4567)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(34567)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEveryOtherDigit(234567)));
```

*Output*

```
[]
[7]
[6]
[5, 7]
[4, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something your second print will only be called once. Note that you're going to need to add some validation on input, because 0 is a valid int and so in its current state your code won't limit the user to 10-99.

A much better way would be to ask them to enter the entire number and then split it in code (for example getting it as a String then splitting it and using `Integer.valueOf()`).

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way to achieve that would be to just get the input as String and split it then to convert them to int

here's the code for that

```
System.out.println ("What is your Student number?");
String stuNum = scn.nextLine();

int [] number = new int[ stuNum.length() ];

for (int i = 0; i < stuNum.length(); i++) {
    number[i] = Character.getNumericValue(stuNum.charAt(i));
}

System.out.println (number);
```